# scala - Convert Map to 2D array

Tags: arrays, scala

I tried to convert my map:

```
private var map=Map[String,Double]()
```

into 2D array, but i had trouble doing it.
Can someone help me please or give me and example of how it's done?
I also had trouble in creating the array, so if you can help me with that i'll be glad.

Thank you for your time, and have a good day! :)

Comment: What are the inputs and what are the outputs (can you provide example, how exactly array should be formated)? What have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

The toArray method looks promising:

```
  res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Double] = Map(a -> 1.1, b -> 2.2, c -> 3.0)

  scala> res6.toArray
  res7: Array[(java.lang.String, Double)] = Array((a,1.1), (b,2.2), (c,3.0))
```

And if you really want an Array instead of tuples:

```
  scala> res6.toArray.map(x => Array(x._1, x._2))
  res8: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(a, 1.1), Array(b, 2.2), Array(c, 3.0))
```

Comment: Alternative syntax to avoid using `_1` and `_2`: `res6.toArray.map{ case(a,b) => Array(a,b) }`

Comment: @Nick or `res6.toArray.map(x => x.productElements.toArray)`

Comment: @om-nom-nom: actually productElements is deprecated and does not exist anymore in 2.10 (now it is called productIterator)